# What does this error mean? (warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm quite new to this whole C++ programming thing and i'm playing around with a "Hello World" program but when I try to build it I always get this error:

[image]

How can I solve this in the easiest way?

Comment: Could you paste the code up? Fixing the warnings is preferable.

Comment: Fix the code that causes the warning. The details should be nearby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project setting has `Treat Warnings As Errors` enabled (`/WX` option). Disable it, or fix all warnings.

[image]

**EDIT**: You may additionally chose to enable error for critical warnings using `#pragma warning` [directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx), and preferably put in `stdafx.h` or similar common header:

```
#pragma warning(error:4127)
```

Comment: No, don't disable it. A newbie should fix all the warnings, and experts also (with some rare exceptions they know about).

Comment: I am not saying not to fix, but not to trigger error for every warning (`Unused parameter` warning doesn't demand immediate fix).

Comment: Or you can use #pragma warning to convert selective warnings as errors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as easiest way is concerned Go to project properties -> configurations properties -> C/C++ -> treats warning as error -> No (/WX-).

Preferably you should deal with these warnings rather than shut your compiler...